# runtime error 438 out of nowhere

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I have been working on a doc with the code below for several days and have had no problems. It's supposed to list any changes to another worksheet onto this worksheet "Log Details". Not sure what I did differently, but now the code give me a runtime 438 error. Does anyone have any ideas??

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
 sSheetName = "1107"
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)
 **Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("1107").Target.Value**  <--This is the code that brings up the error.
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now


 Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean just Target.Value?

Comment: The whole line highlights

Comment: As in Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value

Comment: but Target.Value returns the value it needs to . It's not getting transferred to the "LogDetails" worksheet like it was.

Comment: Yes, the entire line highlights

Comment: I mean drop the Sheets("1107") ... Target refers to the sheet in which the change occurs I think

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see now. That returns a compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference and Target.Value no longer has any value

Comment: NVM that last! I just saw a type

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much:)

Comment: Pleasure. No worries :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference Target refers to the  range within the sheet which changes.
So `Sheets("1107").Target.Value` should be simply `Target.Value` . It will implicitly be the Activesheet.